# Testing Encrypted POST and PUT Methods from Postman or Workbench

Tags: apex, rest-api, encryption

I have a REST API that needs to send and receive AES(256) encryption. All my HTTP methods pass with encrypted data in my unit tests. But I would like to test the API from Postman. I am running into some difficulties and I am not sure if they are related to my programing or the tool.

When I try to send an encrypted body from Postman it does not decrypt into the correct value.

I have written an encryption class that used the Apex crypto class methods. I have been trying to encrypt the request body by copy and pasting from my debug log. And I am guessing that is my problem?

The following encrypts and decrypts back to the correct values.

```
String json = '{"lastName": "patient1114", "email": "test@fake.com", "dob" : "1994-06-01", "zip": "02054, "userName": "testFake1115bdj", "city": "millis", "state": "MA", "address1": "1 Main St"}';

String encrypted = IdentityManagementCrypto.encrypt(json);

System.debug(IdentityManagementCrypto.decrypt(encrypted));
```

But if take the value of

```
System.debug(IdentityManagementCrypto.encrypt(encrypted));
```

And copy it into either Postman or Workbench it fails to decrypt back into the original JSON.

[image]

Below are the methods I am using to encrypt and decrypt data

```
public class IdentityManagementCrypto implements ICrypto{

        public static String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt) {
            Blob key = Blob.valueOf(Label.API_Cypto_Key);
            Blob convertedString = Blob.valueOf(stringToEncrypt);
            Blob encryptedString = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, convertedString);
            String b64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedString);
            System.debug('return value from encrypt method = ' + b64String);

            return b64String;
        }

        public static String decrypt(String stringToDecrypt) {
            Blob key = Blob.valueOf(Label.API_Cypto_Key);
            Blob valueToDecrypt = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(stringToDecrypt);
            Blob decryptedValue = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, valueToDecrypt );
            System.debug('value of decrypted string = ' + decryptedValue);
            return  decryptedValue.toString();
        }
```

Everything works with HTTP Get and encrypting the query string in Postman. But fails with POST and POST and value in the body. I  am hoping someone can tell me if it is the tool and if so, how I can use it for these conditions.

///EDIT

I am getting the following exception ' FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('H' (code 72)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]'

It should be getting thrown from the JSON.deserialize method below

```
 @HttpPost
    global static void createPatient(){
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        System.debug('value of the request body = ' + RestContext.request.requestBody);
        String requestString = IdentityManagementCrypto.decrypt(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString());
        System.debug('value of the request string after decryption = ' + requestString);
        Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestString);

       try{
            AccountClaimMatcher.CreateAccountWrapper wrapper = AccountClaimService.createPatient(params);
            if (wrapper != null) {
                response = RestContext.response;
                response.statusCode = 200;
                String serializedWrapper = (JSON.serialize(wrapper));
                response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(IdentityManagementCrypto.encrypt(serializedWrapper));
                System.debug('debug value of response body in post  = ' + response.responseBody);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 500;
            AccountClaimError[] errors = new AccountClaimError[]{
                    new AccountClaimError('BAD_REQUEST', e.getMessage())
            };
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(errors));
        }
    }
```

When I call system.debug on the request body I am getting a completely different value than the string I tried to pass.

In my debug logs the 'value of decrypted string' = Blob[280]

And the value of 'Request string after decryption' = Hm8YSR8OURO9thwwE8D0aOaDnm3LupH0F4jr1FuYbkgf8XmKvgvlBQgJZeLpr3VOYyXMs9lxkcORalmXYiK052DXUk/sdB67Z5g9xFhXn4kuisZcJNk55k3p3W/6h3q0EhaPQrciRq8+sjvCsi9lZSy4G7C38WAQHSvbPO+VPBVqeLfYbG7nygquPVNdhEkAzq8CKgAGbp+run0C8NmTwh6NMYGTju+KvWeMqfUBTP8DFDJubzVOcX6rOi1jAiZVTMmkfTMTY37vsifXuAMJGQ==

Comment: What error are you getting? Which line does it throw at?

Comment: Off Topic, you may want to re-consider using a Label for your crypto key, since you can't secure it at all. Consider Custom Settings or Custom Metadata for it.

Comment: @sfdcfox I edited the post with the updated.

Comment: @SebastianKessel  you are 100% correct.   I have requested to put it in a managed protected custom setting.

Comment: I am skeptical of designs that use symmetric encryption on data that is (hopefully! presumably!) being sent over an asymmetrically-encrypted HTTPS connection. I have seen many designs where this reflects either a misguided approach to a compliance requirement or a fundamental weakness in user authentication. Not saying either is the case here, but it's something I recommend a lot of careful thought on. Crypto is really, really easy to get wrong.

Comment: In your logs, what does the debug statement for "value of decrypted string" equal?

Comment: @sfdcfox I added in the debug log values in the original post.

Comment: @DavidReed any suggested reading on the topic?

Comment: That's odd. The data looks base64 encoded, but when I decode it, I get what looks like an encrypted string.

Comment: My encrypt method returns a base 64 encoded string.